# Passing values to interface{}

Tags: pointers, go, interface, yaml, unmarshalling

**Short**

The following code does not exactly do what expected: 
https://play.golang.org/p/sO4w4I_Lle

I assume that I mess up some pointer/reference stuff as usual, however I expect my...

```
func unmarshalJSON(in []byte, s interface{}) error
```

... and `encoding/json`s...

```
func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error
```

...to behave the same way (eg. update the referenced passed as second argument).

**Long**

The example above is a minimal reproducer that does not make much sense. This is in order to make it work on the playground. However, an less minimal example that does make sense is this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func unmarshalYAML(in []byte, s interface{}) error {
    var result map[interface{}]interface{}
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(in, &result)
    s = cleanUpInterfaceMap(result)
    // s is printed as expected
    fmt.Println(s) // map[aoeu:[test aoeu] oaeu:[map[mahl:aoec tase:aoeu]]]
    return err
}

func cleanUpInterfaceArray(in []interface{}) []interface{} {
    out := make([]interface{}, len(in))
    for i, v := range in {
        out[i] = cleanUpMapValue(v)
    }
    return out
}

func cleanUpInterfaceMap(in map[interface{}]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    out := make(map[string]interface{})
    for k, v := range in {
        out[fmt.Sprintf("%v", k)] = cleanUpMapValue(v)
    }
    return out
}

func cleanUpMapValue(v interface{}) interface{} {
    switch v := v.(type) {
    case []interface{}:
        return cleanUpInterfaceArray(v)
    case map[interface{}]interface{}:
        return cleanUpInterfaceMap(v)
    case string:
        return v
    default:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%v", v)
    }
}

func main() {
    s := make(map[string]interface{})
    b := []byte(`---
aoeu:
- test
- aoeu
oaeu:
- { tase: aoeu, mahl: aoec}
`)
    err := unmarshalYAML(b, &s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // s is still an empty map
    fmt.Println(s) // map[]
}
```

The idea is to unmarshal YAML to `map[string]interface{}` (instead of `map[interface{}]interface{}`) is order to allow to serialize to JSON (where identifiers need to be strings). The `unmarshalYAML` function should provide the same func signture as `yaml.Unmarshal`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using Type assertion

Inside your `unmarshalJSON()` function the parameter `s` behaves like a local variable. When you assign something to it:

```
s = result
```

It will only change the value of the local variable.

Since you want it to work with changing the value of a `*map[string]interface{}` and that is what you pass to it, you could use a simple [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to obtain the map pointer from it, and pass this pointer to `json.Unmarshal()`:

```
func unmarshalJSON(in []byte, s interface{}) error {
    if m, ok := s.(*map[string]interface{}); !ok {
        return errors.New("Expecting *map[string]interface{}")
    } else {
        return json.Unmarshal(in, m)
    }
}
```

Try your modified, working example on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hhVZpvaPKw).

#### Just passing it along

Also note that however this is completely unnecessary as [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) is also defined to take the destination as a value of type `interface{}`, the same thing you have. So you don't even have to do anything just pass it along:

```
func unmarshalJSON(in []byte, s interface{}) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(in, s)
}
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cQqKBo6_j9).

#### With a variable of function type

As an interesting thing note that the *signature* of your `unmarshalJSON()` and the library function `json.Unmarshal()` is identical:

```
// Yours:
func unmarshalJSON(in []byte, s interface{}) error

// json package
func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error
```

This means there is another option, that is you could use a variable named `unmarshalJSON` of a [function type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types), and just simply assign the function value `json.Unmarshal`:

```
var unmarshalJSON func([]byte, interface{}) error = json.Unmarshal
```

Now you have a variable `unmarshalJSON` which is of function type, and you can call it as if it would be a function:

```
err := unmarshalJSON(b, &s)
```

Try this function value on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oZiWI-124c).

#### Now on to your `unmarshalYAML()` function

In your `unmarshalYAML()` you do the same mistake:

```
s = cleanUpInterfaceMap(result)
```

This will only change the value of your local `s` variable (parameter), and it will not "populate" the map (pointer) passed to `unmarshalYAML()`.

Use the type assertion technique detailed above to obtain the pointer from the `s` `interface{}` argument, and once you have that, you can change the *pointed* object (the "outside" map).

```
func unmarshalYAML(in []byte, s interface{}) error {
    var dest *map[string]interface{}
    var ok bool
    if dest, ok = s.(*map[string]interface{}); !ok {
        return errors.New("Expecting *map[string]interface{}")
    }

    var result map[interface{}]interface{}
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(in, &result); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    m := cleanUpInterfaceMap(result)

    // m holds the results, dest is the pointer that was passed to us,
    // we can just set the pointed object (map):
    *dest = m
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks @icza! would you mind to have a look at the "Long" example I provided? I understand what you are pointing out but have not found a way to apply this to unmarshalYAML() yet...

Comment: @sontags But that's exactly what happens. More or less. In the above example I don't check if a map or a `nil` map value was passed, it will just "overwrite" the map variable that was passed. But it will be visible from the outside.

Comment: @sontags Additionally you could check if `*dest` is not `nil`, and if it's not, you could add (copy) values to that map, but it's clearer to just assign as that map might already contain values, giving further confusion where those elements come from (e.g. were already in the map, or were the result of unmarshalling).

Comment: All fine! it took me to long to write my comment, meanwhile you updated your answer! Thanks very much!