# Casting interface{} to calculated in runtime Type

Tags: go

Here is schematic example what I need:

```
func decode(data []byte, target interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    decoded := target.(reflect.TypeOf(target)) // pseudocode
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &decoded)
    ...
```

I found several similar questions on SO, but all solutions are about switch by `target.(type)`. This is not the best solution what I look for.

Also I found solution with reflection:

```
decoded := reflect.ValueOf(target).Convert(reflect.TypeOf(target))
// fmt.Printf("%T", decoded) == reflect.Value
```

But I couldn't understand how to get struct from `reflect.Value` to pass it to `json.Unmarshal` function.

**How this `decode` function will be used?**

I have multiple requests in different structures. I can determine what struct I should use to decode request. I have mapping between request type and structure like this `map[RequestMethod]interface{}`.

Schematic version looks like this:

```
func hydrate(data []byte) (interface{}, error) {
    var base baseResponse

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &base); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    target, ok := methodsMap[Method(base.Method)]

    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("Trying to hydrate data with unknown method: " + base.Method)
    }

    decoded, err := decode(data, target) // Expected target type.
```

Added:

If we pass our `target` to `json.Unmarshal` without casting to it type we will obtain `map`. Example:

```
func decode(data []byte, target interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &target)
    // fmt.Printf("%T", target) == map[string]interface{} not struct.
```

**Solution**

Thanks to [@icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza) we found solution:

```
func hydrate(data []byte) (interface{}, error) {
    var base baseResponse

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &base); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    target, ok := methodsMap[Method(base.Method)]

    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("Trying to hydrate data with unknown method: " + base.Method)
    }

    // Clone request draft struct.
    decoded := reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(target).Type()).Interface()
    err := decode(data, decoded)
    ...
```

Related links:

[Golang interface{} type misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829941/golang-interface-type-misunderstanding/38830638#38830638)

[How to copy an interface value in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851500/how-to-copy-an-interface-value-in-go/37851764#37851764)

Comment: This seems very unnecessary. Simply passing `target` to `json.Unmarshal` should work fine for you.

Comment: @TimCooper, if we pass `target` with type `interface{}` to `json.Unmarshal` we will obtain `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: Show us how you call this `decode()` function. Most likely you pass a wrong value.

Comment: @icza added usage example to question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing values to interface{}](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35449654/1705598); and [Golang interface{} type misunderstanding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829941/golang-interface-type-misunderstanding/38830638#38830638).

Comment: @icza this question is very similar to my use case but I understand why I obtain `map` instead of `struct`. So my question is about casting not unmarshaling.

Comment: @AlexBor If you read my other answers: you don't need to convert it to anything. Where you go wrong is calling your `decode()` function: you must pass a pointer to a struct to it. Inside `decode()`, you just have to pass the `interface{}` value to `json.Unmarshal()`.

Comment: @icza I can't pass pointer to `methodsMap[Method(base.Method)]` struct because it contains draft struct for this request. I'm searching for solution to create a copy for this struct. Then I will be able to send its pointer to `decode()`. After all I will update my question. If you know better way for duplicating structure (creating new instance with the same type) - I will be very grateful for the advice.

Comment: @AlexBor To copy a value wrapped in an interface: [How to copy an interface value in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851500/how-to-copy-an-interface-value-in-go/37851764#37851764)

Comment: @icza in your answer you use casting to specified type `reflect.New(...).Interface().(User)`. In my question I ask how I can specify type without hardcoding it?

Comment: @AlexBor Just leave out the final type assertion. I used that there because I worked with it afterwards. Just use `reflect.New(...).Interface()`.

Comment: @icza Thank you! It works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code to create a copy of the draft struct and unmarshal to it:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(methodsMap[Method(base.Method)])
pv := reflect.New(t)
err := json.Unmarshal(p, pv.Interface())
return pv.Elem().Interface(), err  // pv.Elem() dereferences ptr
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/H8capqmxp5)

Comment: you are a wonderful human being -- tried 'all the combinations' but this one, and was banging my head against the wall. Thank you thank you thank you!